# TypeError: chrome.setDefaultService is not a function

Tags: javascript

Microsoft Windows [versão 10.0.19045.2965]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

C:\Users\Dalian\Downloads\Extras Temp\api-aviator-betano>npm install

up to date, audited 148 packages in 3s

17 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

C:\Users\Dalian\Downloads\Extras Temp\api-aviator-betano>npm start

> api-aviator-betano@1.0.0 start
> node src/server.js

C:\Users\Dalian\Downloads\Extras Temp\api-aviator-betano\src\service\painel-service.js:12
chrome.setDefaultService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromeDriver.path).build());
^

TypeError: chrome.setDefaultService is not a function
at Object. (C:\Users\Dalian\Downloads\Extras Temp\api-aviator-betano\src\service\painel-service.js:12:8)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1267:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1125:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:965:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\Dalian\Downloads\Extras Temp\api-aviator-betano\src\server.js:3:48)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1267:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1321:10)

Node.js v20.1.0

C:\Users\Dalian\Downloads\Extras Temp\api-aviator-betano>

I tried to run this https://github.com/epedrotti7/api-aviator-betano following the instructions contained therein. But it gives an error when I run npm start

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.